# No Synchronize Model with Database in Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, schema, mysql-workbench, synchronization

I'd like to synchronize a model in Mysql workbench. However, I can't find the wizard following [these steps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-synchronization.html) in the docs. How do I enable this feature?

I'm running 6.3.3.0 (latest) on Mac Os X .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Home page open a model ( bottom part of the window ) or create one if you dont have any.
Select the Mysql Model tab on the top.
Open the Database menu on the top menu row, and the `Syncronize Model...` and the `Syncronize with Any Source...` should be the second and third option from the bottom.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I guess I misunderstood this function. I was actually looking for something to synchronise database - database. My bad.

Comment: Thank you, the documentation was updated accordingly (how to start this wizard was clarified), the changes will show up online within a couple of hours. Also, a feature request was submitted to allow executing "Synchronize With Any Source" without a model present.

Comment: @PhilipOlson, how can you sync a model to any source if no model is present actually? Isn't that an oxymoron in itself?

Comment: @MikeLischke, you can use Syncronize with any source to get the differences of two database, and it can give you a sql script of it.
I usually use it to create db update from development environment for the live db.